# How to combine all values of a single column into single string variable using python?

Tags: python

I have dataframe with column name "Column Name"

```
column Name
ab
cd
ef
gh
ij 
kl
```

I have an 18K rows in single column. And I want to convert like this using python..
Expected Output: `abcdefghijkl`

Comment: What type of "dataframe"? I guess pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`one_string = ''.join(df['Column Name'].tolist())`

Answer (score 2):

If you use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
print(df['column Name'].sum())
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijkl
```